# BI Publisher 12c report running slow after linking data sets

Tags: bi-publisher

I have an Oracle 12c BI Publisher report that I am linking an Oracle db data set and a Oracle data warehouse data set that is running very slow and is not displaying that it is processing data as it did in 11g. The report eventually returns the error message, "user requested cancel operation.." which I believe indicates that the report timed out. Does anyone have suggestions on how I could fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried running the SQL in a SQL development tool to see how fast it returns results?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. My org frowns on creating dblinks, not sure how to test without it.

Comment: so you are just writing the SQL by hand in notepad or something, and adding to the data definition in BI Publisher, and running the SQL there as your first and only test? Usually developers create/test in an SQL developer directly connected to the database first. Can you share the SQL statement(s) that is/are giving the problem?

Comment: No, I tested the sql in SQL developer first then put them in datasets in BI Publisher and then  I linked them in BI Publisher. My org seems to frown on creating dblinks because they say they are difficult to support (patching, etc). Is there a way of referencing two different Oracle dbs in SQL Developer without dblinks?